# Django uploaded file doesn't process

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, pandas

I'm building a Django web-app where the user needs to upload a file. This file should go through a machine-learning alogritme after that the results will be presented on a different page.

right now it works if I have text fields present for every feature but when I want to upload a csv file(the csv file is called test.csv) put it in a pandas dataframe the resultpage doesn't show and it looks like the csv file isn't processed.

what it should do is if file is uploaded keep the uploaded file in memory process it and return the output on the results page.

**HTML**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
  <div class="content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="card card-tasks">
          <h1> </h1>
          <form action="{% url 'result' %}">
            {% csrf_token %}

            <p>temp_normal:</p>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="temp_normal">
            <br>

            <p>hour:</p>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="hour">
            <br>

            <p>hour_x:</p>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="hour_x">
            <br>

            <p>hour_y:</p>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="hour_y">
            <br>

            <input class="form-control" type="submit" value='Submit'>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="card card-tasks">
          <form action="{% url "result" %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="name" class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 control-label">File: </label>
              <div class="col-md-8">
                  <input type="file" name="csv_file" id="csv_file" required="True" class="form-control">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
                   <button class="btn btn-primary"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload" style="margin-right:5px;"></span>Upload </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

**views.py**

```
def handle_uploaded_file(f):
    with open('test.csv', 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in f.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)


# custom method for generating predictions
def getPredictions(data):
    import pickle
    model = pickle.load(open("test_model.sav", "rb"))
    prediction = model.predict(data)
    return prediction


@login_required
def result(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])
            data = form
            data = pd.read_csv(data,header=0)
            result = getPredictions(data)
            return render(request, 'result.html', {'result': result})
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: do you need a `type="submit"` on the upload button?

Comment: still doesn't work after I've added the ```type="submit"```

Comment: try adding your form from the context -> `{{ form }}` instead of your html file input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
  <form action="{% url "result" %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name" class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 control-label">File: </label>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        {{ form }}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload" style="margin-right:5px;"></span>Upload </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

as we discussed for the view:

```
@login_required
def result(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            file = request.FILES['file']
            handle_uploaded_file(file)
            data = pd.read_csv(file,header=0)
            result = getPredictions(data)
            return render(request, 'result.html', {'result': result})
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: stuff is happening thanks to this code. but i'm gettting an error ```Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'djangoweek.forms.UploadFileForm'>```

Comment: I think this is because pandas doesn't like this. ```\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py, line 243, in get_filepath_or_buffer```

Comment: yeah i was gonna say looks like a pandas error - need to see whats in your pickled function

Comment: you mean the picked .sav file? or something else?

Comment: yeah the original *model that was pickled

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223693/discussion-between-ultiseeker-and-nihilok).